# Getting an Authorization Code on Spotify API (POST request)

Tags: python, post, spotify

This is a spotify [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#list-of-scopes) I'm following. Out of the 3 options of 'Authorization Flows', I'm trying the '**Authorization Code Flow**'.

Finished step **1. Have your application request authorization**.

Stuck at step **2. Have your application request refresh and access tokens**

It's asking to make a POST request that contains *the parameters encoded in ´application/x-www-form-urlencoded as defined in the OAuth 2.0 specification:*. Here is what I've done so far with my limited knowledge and google search.

```
import requests
import base64
from html import unescape 

url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"

params = {
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "code": <authorization code I got from step 1>,
    "redirect_uri": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", 
}

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36",    
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization" : base64.b64encode("{}:{}".format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET).encode('UTF-8')).decode('ascii')
}

html = requests.request('post', url, headers=headers, params=params, data=None) 
print(html.text)
```

result, with response code 400

```
{"error":"invalid_client"}
```

What should I do to make it work? I thought I got all the params right.

Comment: The `Authorization` header should start with `Basic `. You could also use the `auth=` parameter.

Comment: You may already have tried this but there's an app called postman which allows you to manually create HTTP requests for testing.

Comment: @t.m.adam That was just it. Thank you!